# String gets cut off during RC4 decryption

Tags: c++, encryption

**EDIT:**

It seems like the error lies within the `ReadResource()` function. When printing the output before decryption the code is already cut off.

**Old Text:**

I am storing a RC4 encrypted string inside my application's resource. Because RC4 Encryption has a maximum string size I split the large string into substrings and divide them with a delimiter.

Now, my app is supposed to read from resource. Then split them using the delimiter, decrypt each substring and combine them again.

When trying this with 'testestestestest........test' as string it works, but if I use for example 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr' it cuts of part of the string during decryption.

This is the RC4-Code:

```
char* rc4_crypt( char *s, size_t datalen, char *d, size_t keylen)

{
unsigned char S[SIZE];
char *data = s;
char *key = d;
int i,j,k,tmp;

  for(i = 0; i < SIZE;i++)
   S[i] = i;

  for(j = i = 0; i < SIZE;i++) {
   j = (j + S[i] + key[i%keylen]) % SIZE;
   tmp = S[i];
   S[i] = S[j];
   S[j] = tmp;   
  }

  for(i = j = k = 0; k < datalen;k++) {
   i = (i + 1) % SIZE;
   j = (j + S[i]) % SIZE;
   tmp = S[i];
   S[i] = S[j];
   S[j] = tmp;
   tmp = S[(S[i] + S[j]) % SIZE];
   data[k] ^= tmp;
  }
  return data;
}
```

This is the code handling the splitting:

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, 
                                char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while(std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    return split(s, delim, elems);
}
void print (std::string &elem)
{
    //This is because somehow 'ul' is still included 
    //as an extra element, this sorts it out
    if(elem.length() !=2) { 
        cout << elem << '\n';
        char *output = rc4_crypt((char *)elem.c_str(),
            strlen(elem.c_str()),key, strlen(key));
        cout << output << '\n';
        FinalString = FinalString + output;
    }

}
```

And this is my main function:

```
int main() {
  char *output;
  output = ReadResource();
  std::string stringy;
  stringy = output;
  std::vector<std::string> splitted = split(stringy,'+ul+');
  for_each (splitted.begin(), splitted.end(), print);
    cout << endl;
  cout << FinalString << '\n';
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

I am adding the RC4 function I use in vb.net to encrypt the code. Maybe this can help:

```
Private Shared Function Proper_RC4(ByVal Input As Byte(), ByVal Key As Byte()) As Byte()

        Dim i, j, swap As UInteger
        Dim s As UInteger() = New UInteger(255) {}
        Dim Output As Byte() = New Byte(Input.Length - 1) {}

        For i = 0 To 255
            s(i) = i
        Next

        For i = 0 To 255
            j = (j + Key(i Mod Key.Length) + s(i)) And 255
            swap = s(i) 'Swapping of s(i) and s(j)
            s(i) = s(j)
            s(j) = swap
        Next

        i = 0 : j = 0
        For c = 0 To Output.Length - 1
            i = (i + 1) And 255
            j = (j + s(i)) And 255
            swap = s(i) 'Swapping of s(i) and s(j)
            s(i) = s(j)
            s(j) = swap
            Output(c) = Input(c) Xor s((s(i) + s(j)) And 255)
        Next

        Return Output
    End Function
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is the ReadResource() function:

```
char *ReadResource() {
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    HMODULE ModuleH = GetModuleHandle(buffer);
    HRSRC Res = FindResource(ModuleH, L"1", L"DATA");
    HGLOBAL GlobalH = LoadResource(ModuleH,Res);
    void * ptr = LockResource(GlobalH);
    Size = SizeofResource(ModuleH,Res);
    CHAR *m_pResourceBuffer = new CHAR[Size];
    if (m_pResourceBuffer != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(m_pResourceBuffer, ptr, Size);

    }
    return m_pResourceBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to split like that?  Any reasonable encryption scheme should allow multiple buffers to be encrypted/decrypted as if they were a single stream.

Comment: RC4 does not have a maximum length. Assuming SIZE is set correctly to 256,  your `rc4_crypt()` function should work for any input size.

Comment: That what I thought too. However, when I tried to pass large strings they got cut off. This happens only during the decryption, I use vb.net to encrypt my strings and the encrypted output seems to be okay. It must be something in the RC4 Function I posted. But I haven't figured out why

Comment: @duskwuff and yes, SIZE is set to 256.

Comment: I just want to remind you that you must never ever reuse a key with RC4, and that RC4 suffers from related key attacks, so simply concatenating a nonce and the key to generate a unique key doesn't work either. And you should throw away the first 3072 or so output bytes, to avoid the strong biases those bytes have. | Or you could use a cipher that's not that annoying to use. RC4 is old, and doesn't hold up well compared to modern ciphers. | Or are you using RC4 just for obfuscation? In that case it doesn't really matter, since it's much easier to extract the key than to exploit the crypto flaws

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `ReadResource` is reading the encrypted data.  If so, then that data could easily have a zero in the middle of it.  That zero would be treated as a NULL terminator when assigned to `string`.  Thus it would only decrypt up until that first zero. It could be that the first example did not end up with a zero in the encrypted result, but the second example did.

But as others have already pointed out in the comments, there should be no need with RC4 to break it into pieces.  It should be able to encrypt it all in one call.  And in reality, it is bad (insecure) to keep encrypting with the same key while resetting the s-box each time.  The result is very vulnerable.  This is described some [in this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher_attack).

If you encrypt it as a single stream, then the logic becomes much simpler to deal with.  When you read the data (e.g., via `ReadResource`) you also need to get the length.  That function will need to return the length.  Then use that length in the call to decrypt the data.

Comment: Thank you! I figured that this could be the issue, but I wasn't sure. Any advice on how to bypass this? I am new to c++ so I am not familiar with the different data types. Maybe this already caused the cut off in the first place (before I used splitting). I would be very thankful if you could help me out here!

Comment: I added a bit more info.  Basically, I think it would be best to not use the code that splits up the data into chunks unless there is some other compelling reason that it is needed.

Comment: I tried that before, but the String got cut off too. This is how I called the RC4 function before i added splitting:
`char *output = rc4_crypt(ReadResource(), strlen(ReadResource()),key, strlen(key));` But it still got cut off and I can't figure out why.

Comment: As I already said, ReadResource will need to return the length of data that it read.  You cannot use strlen() if it is encrypted data; there may be a zero in it.  If the data is long enough, there will be a zero for sure.

Comment: I tried this, I stored the Resource size using `SizeofResource()` and it is larger. So you were correct that `strlen()` causes data loss. But when I try to use the resource size for the decryption method I get weird output. I also checked the length of the encryption output and it is the same size as the wrong size from `strlen()` so there must be an error in the RC4 function...

Comment: If you are assigning that char* output variable to the std::string, and then decrypting that buffer, it still will not work.  The assignment of an encrypted buffer to std::string like that would never work unless you can guarantee that there are no zeros in the data.

Comment: Okay, what data/buffer type can I use to receive the complete resource? Maybe already in the `ReadResource`? I added it to my original text. Sorry for asking such questions but c++ is just so different from vb.net

Comment: The char* buffer should be fine.  And you have the size in ReadResource (variable `Size` although I don't see it declared so I don't know how that works).  You need to pass that back (e.g., an output parameter by reference perhaps).

Comment: I think the error lies in the `ReadResource()` I just did `cout << m_pResourceBuffer` and the encrypted bytes are already cut off.

Comment: If you used strlen() when writing the resource after encrypting it, then everything after the first zero would not get written.

Comment: No the encrypted code in the resource is complete, I used my function in vb.net and it works(I also check it with an Resource Editor) . But when I try to read the encrypted code from the resource using `ReadResource()` it gets cut off even before decrypting it

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with this code.

warning: multi-character constant, `std::getline` uses a one character delimiter. This is also the reason `ul` shows up in the array of `splitted`

```
splitted = split(stringy,'+ul+');
```

You modify the returned string from `c_str()`

```
rc4_crypt((char *)elem.c_str(), ...);
```

From [`std::string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

> A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.
>   The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value.
>
> The pointer returned may be invalidated by further calls to other member functions that modify the object.

And finally the most likely candidate for the cutoff is

```
data[k] ^= tmp;
```

If `data[k] == tmp`, then this will give zero and your string is truncated at this position.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds very promising. Do you know, how to fix the last "candidate" ?

Comment: @Lotzki I'm not familiar with RC4, but from the code, I think this is intended. It seems, you don't get a readable encrypted string. If you don't want your *original* string garbled, then just use some output buffer. If you want readable encrypted text, use base64 encoding, for example.

Comment: I added the RC4 code from vb.net, maybe there are some translation errors I am missing.

Comment: @Lotzki Your translation looks fine so far, except the fact, that you overwrite your input. Since NUL bytes are expected, as it seems, you cannot use strings, but must use a char array or vector.

Comment: @Olaf:  The XOR operation is correct for RC4.  It is perfectly valid (and expected) for the output to contain zeros.  In fact, it would be expected that all values 0 to 255 appear in basically equal numbers.

Comment: @MarkWilkins I don't question the XOR. Only the modification of an intrinsic read only input variable. Thanks for the confirmation of zeros in the output.